# Add New Project -> Class Library (Engine) targets the .NET 2.0 framework

Tags: arcgis-engine

Any one have comments on why the ArgGis Extensions in the 10 framework still target the .NET 2.0 framework?

For clarification do the following steps in Visual Studio: 
Add New Project -> Class Library (Engine)  -> Click properties -> see that it targets the .NET 2.0 framework.

Comment: With VS2010 I added a new engine library targeting .NET 3.5. I chose 3.5 in the dropdownlist in the new project dialog.

Comment: It's possible to vote for 4.0 support here: http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=087300000008Dwn&returnUrl=%2Fapex%2FideaList%3Fc%3D09a300000004xET%26category%3DArcGIS%2BEngine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A framework isn't associated with a particular template. The target framework can be selected when you create the project.

1. Click File, then New, then Project...
2. Click the drop-down above the template files (to the left of "Sort by:") and select the appropriate framework.
3. Click OK

Answer (score 1):

As an example, I remember some organizations using GIS were considering moving from IE 6 to 7 when IE 8 was released. I don't think there is much demand for 4.0 yet and I don't think many people bothered to read up on it much either.